RPi5: gpiozero KeyError and SOC peripheral base address error
I am trying to blink an LED on/off to make sure my raspberry pi 5 is working correctly. It is a brand new RPi5. I have a GPIO Extension Board off my GPIO prongs. My circuit is very simple it should not be the problem. The LED is hooked up to the GPIO17 connection. Here is my Python code
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(17)

try:
    while True:
        led.on()
        print('...LED ON')
        sleep(0.5)
        led.off()
        print('LED OFF...')

        sleep(0.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

This is the error I get when running this.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:295: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from lgpio: 'can not open gpiochip'
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 408, in pin
    pin = self.pins[info]
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: PinInfo(number=11, name='GPIO17', names=frozenset({'17', 'GPIO17', 17, 'WPI0', 'BOARD11', 'J8:11', 'BCM17'}), pull='', row=6, col=1, interfaces=frozenset({'', 'spi', 'gpio', 'dpi', 'uart'}))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevinkrupa13/raphael-kit/python-pi5/1.1.1_BlinkingLed_zero.py", line 6, in <module>
    led = LED(17)
          ^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 103, in __call__
    self = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 192, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, active_high=active_high,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 74, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 75, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 549, in __init__
    pin = self.pin_factory.pin(pin)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 410, in pin
    pin = self.pin_class(self, info)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 101, in __init__
    GPIO.setup(self._number, GPIO.IN, self.GPIO_PULL_UPS[self._pull])
RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address

My python script has full privileges as well. I know this issue has been mentioned multiple times across different sites, but I can't seem to find a good solution to it anywhere. Hoping somebody who has seen this can help! If anybody knows of a good solution, please link it!

I had the same problem. Make the newest updates and it will work now. I think it's a problem of the gpiochip folder naming. Good luck!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
